# Convert string to INT in C# (When String is 'E0305' To convert INT is not Work

Tags: c#, .net, string, math, converters

I want to convert string to int but some time is not working.

Here is my code:

```
public static int ToInt(String pStr)
{
     return Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Val(pStr));
}

Int i = ToInt("F0005");
```

Output is 0 - it works fine.

But when I pass in a value like this

```
Int i = ToInt("E0305");
```

Then I get an error "Out-of-range exception".

I have a mix of values, some are `int` and some are strings; I want to pass each and every value in loop and convert it to `int`, but when I pass this value then I get an error.

Comment: I think it sees `"E0305"` as a value with exponential notation: `"1E305"`, which would be out of range.

Comment: Are the values actually HEX numbers?

Comment: Use `Int.TryParse` in C# - it will return a `NULL` if the string cannot be converted to an `int` but it won't error out

Comment: Why does F0005 evaluate to 0? And what would E0305 evaluate to? Are these hexadecimal numbers, or are you trying to decode some other format?

Comment: @marc_s Not to be pedantic, but `Int.TryParse` does return `false` if the string cannot be converted to an `int` ;-). And yes, that function would be the way to go.

Comment: @Cleptus: sorry - you're absolutely right, of course!! Guess my brain's too much in T-SQL these days (where `TRY_CAST` returns `NULL` )

Comment: @PoulBak my be it's convert exponential notation: "1E305" that's why not out of range.

Comment: i use `TryParse' it is return failed then i was pass as 0. it is work for me. thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to skip invalid string value, it is better to use `TryParse` instead of returning 0 (which might be valid value). At your calling code it should look like this:

```
string val = "F0005";
if (int.TryParse(val, out int i) {
   // parse success. you can use i here
}
else {
   // parse failed. 
}
```

If you really want it to be 0, this should work

```
string val = "F0005";
int i = int.TryParse(val, out int x) ? x : 0;
```

Comment: FYI, if `int.TryParse` returns false then the out int value will be set to the default vlaue of 0 so just `int.TryParse(value out int i);` would set `i` to 0 if it fails to parse it.

Comment: @juharr well yes it is documented so, but for the sake of readability I don't feel I should touch the value in case of parsing fail because by just looking at the code it would not be immediately obvious that the out value will be 0 in that case.

Comment: @tia thanks you, it is work for me because when i try to convert INT that time  I think it sees "E0305" as a value with exponential notation: "1E305", which would be out of range. so i try to convert TRYPARSE() then it's work because it's not parse failed so i return 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in C# alone without VB.NET library

```
public static int ToInt(string pStr)
{
     return int.Parse(pstr);
}
```

Noted that this will throw exception if `pStr` is not a valid integer string. In your case, it might also throw exception if the value is too big, which you might need `long` instead to hold bigger numbers.

```
public static long ToInt64(string pStr)
{
     return long.Parse(pstr);
}
```

Also, I just noticed that you are trying to parse "E0305" which is not really a valid format (as far as I know). The closest one is "1E305", which means 1 with 305 zeroes afterward. If you need to parse an integer that big, you might need `BigInteger`

```
public static BigInteger ToBigInteger(string pStr)
{
     return BigInteger.Parse(pstr, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
}
```

The `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent` part is there to allow parsing the number in exponent representation.

Comment: Also if string could have 'strange' values is better to use TryParse() instead parse

Comment: Looks like OP wants to return `0` when incorrect data was passed to the function (when they use `F0005` as input and say "_Output is 0 - it works fine_") so you should consider focusing your answer in `TryParse()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `int.TryParse()` method for those cases where you have some unexpected and you do not want exceptions in proces of parsing them.

Use case for it would be:

```
var isValid = int.TryParse(pStr, out int result);
```

Also another benefit of using it is that you have return value that provides you a way to handle unsuccessful parsing call.